# Pass a value between screens in odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a model with a many2one field which allows me to create new records, so I want to pass one of the values selected in the Model A to the floating creation window of the Model B.

I was reading about using context, but I'm not sure if that can be used in this case.

```
Model A - Feature
Desc         >Char
Alternatives > O2M(Alternative,feature_id) 

Model B - Alternative
Desc         >Char
feature_id   >M2O(feature)
```

**EDIT I: Adding relations between my models**

I'm actually using 4 models, version, feature, alternative and tag, I want to create a version for each feature I have, a feature have alternatives and every alternative have tags

In the version I want to select the feature and then can add the tags related to the alternatives of the feature.

```
**version**
feature_id      m2o>feature
desc            char
tag_ids         o2m>tag,alternative_id

**tag** 
caption         char
alternative_id  m2o>alternative

**alternative**
desc            char
feature_id      m2o>feature
tag_ids         o2m>tag,alternative_id

**feature**
desc            char
alternative_ids o2m>alternative,feature_id
```

Can I use the context to create new tags on a version? or I have to use a related fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pass a value to the form of the m2o field:

```
   <field name="m2o_field_name" context="{'default_field_name': field_name}"/>
```

example:

```
  <field name="partner_id" context="{'default_email': company_email}" />
```

here in my model a have m2o partner_id and a field named company_email and when i click create and edit what ever the value of company_email will be passed to email field in partner form.

you can pass static value like `'default_name': 'charif'` or you can pass value of a field named `field_example` like this  `'default_name': field_example`

EDITS:

```
version -->  feature    <--- alternative  <---  tags
```

ok first you need to create m2o from tags to features:

```
    # don't forget store=True so you can create a o2m 
    feature_id = fields.Many2one(related='alternative_id.feature_id', store=True, readonly=true)
```

now create a o2m from features to tags.

```
    tag_ids = fields.One2many('tag.model.name', 'feature_id', 'Tags')
```

and here you can create a related field from version to feature tags.

```
    tag_ids = fields.One2many(related='feature_id.tag_ids', readonly=true)
```

Comment: If I use this the context will get setted on the page load? because I want to change the context depending a field selected in the first model, ill modify my example code.

Comment: i think related field will do it did you try it

Comment: yes im trying it but can't figure how to turn a one2many field into a related one

Comment: you want to create o2m tags in version

Comment: yes, and I'm trying to add the related arg to the o2m field but I cant reach the feature module through the tag. like tag.alternative_id.feature_id.id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143332/discussion-between-nmenam-and-cherif-odoo).